# SQL CASE Statement Evaluating NULL but only returning NULL

Tags: null, sql-server-2000, case

I am trying to identify blocks of time in our scheduling system that are open and the only way I can do that is to check if the description of the block is NULL.

The times are stored in the database as INT so this case statement is used to rebuild either 3 or 4 character INT into a DATETIME.

This is my code. 'stm' is the start time of the block.

```
case
when len(sd.sd_stm)=4 AND sd.sd_block_display IS NULL THEN convert(datetime,'2013-01-01 ' + substring(convert(varchar,sd.sd_stm),1,2)+':'+substring(convert(varchar,sd.sd_stm),3,2))
when len(sd.sd_stm)=3 AND sd.sd_block_display IS NULL THEN convert(datetime,'2013-01-01 ' + substring(convert(varchar,sd.sd_stm),1,1)+':'+substring(convert(varchar,sd.sd_stm),2,2))
ELSE '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
END
```

Sample Input - stm = 730
Desired Output - 2013-01-01 07:30:00.000
Actual Output - 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000

The problem I seem to be having is once it evaluates block_display as NULL it's returning null for the value of stm.  When I do this code for block_display IS NOT NULL it executes fine.

Any advice please?

Comment: You probably have to show more of the code than what you have here, also some sample data and expected results would help.

Comment: can you give example of the format of the int dates and the actual datetime the correspond to.

Comment: The issue isn't the dates...it's evaluating a NULL value of the block_display as true so the code in the THEN section executes.

Comment: "it's evaluating a NULL value of the block_display" - you probably (hopefully) know what you mean by that. Me, I've no idea. Please try to more carefully explain what's happening here, ideally with actual examples of input, desired output, actual output.

Comment: I am checking the length of stm AND to see if block_display IS NULL.  If that is true then reformatting the value of stm into a DATETIME.  But what I am observing is if block_display IS NULL the entire statement is returning as NULL